# Returning all entries in a C# list matching an int

Tags: c#, list

I have a list that has the following:

```
class GetMyList
{
    public int searchInt { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Type { get; set; }
    public string Retype { get; set; }
    public string Time { get; set; }
    public string City { get; set; }
    public DateTime dateHere { get; set; }
}
```

This list could have multiple entries for each int (ie the searchInt 1 could have an entry for 4/11/2017 and another for 4/12/2017).

How do I return ALL of the entries that match the searchInt of 1 in my example above? Preferably so I can just access the dateHere field but it would be nice to know the others, if that matters.

Comment: Have you tried: `list.Where(entry => entry.searchInt == 1)` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could simply utilize Linq.

```
var filter = collection.Where(search => search.searchInt == 1);
```

The `Where` would in essence match on a predicate, so in this case all items that evaluate to true in my statement, will be returned.

Comment: I'm not familiar with LINQ (sounds like I need to do so), but I was able to adapt what I wanted from the code based on a foreach loop + this.  Thanks to you both for the help!